# How to version control newsrc, e.g. Gnus .newsrc.eld in git

Tags: gnus, version-control

BRIEF: like the title says, I want to know how best to version control newsrc files such as Gnus .newsrc.eld  and possibly the legacy .newsrc

By "version control"  I mean something like git/hg/rcs/cvs. NOT simply .~1~, .~2~...

---+ DETAIL

I am  religious about version control systems like git/hg/rcs/cvs. Tools that allow me to keep multiple versions,  diff them to see what has changed, comment changes, and possibly restore to an earlier state.

I do not mean simply keeping extra copies around in the file system.  in particular, not emacs's  .~1~, .~2~, ...  controlled by the unfortunately named  variable `version-control`. Although I suppose the  main difference is that proper version control tools  make it easy to manage.

Restoring to earlier state is particularly important in situations such as what happened to me last night,  when I seem to accidentally have killed most of my Gnus/IMAP/Gmail groups  because of an unfortunate interaction of Gnus  unmodified key-bindings and  Dragon speech recognition/dictation.

(Gnus groups ==  IMAP folders ==  Gmail labels)

I spent quite a bit of time organizing several hundred Gnus groups into Gnus topics.  It was quite annoying to have to redo it.

This is not just a Gnus/topics problem.  I recall having similar issues in the last century using newsreaders that used the older .newsrc and .newsrc.el files --  no topics, but remembering which of several hundred Gnus groups you want to subscribe to is also something you want to version control.

Unfortunately many of the  tools that use .newsrc* files can suffer file corruption problems.  I remember this from the  last century, and I have suffered several instances since I  restarted using emacs Gnus a month or so ago.

One problem is that the .newsrc and .newsrc.eld files  keep track of several different types of information:

(SLOW) Information that changes relatively slowly, under user control

- Gnu's mapping of  groups into topics,  and their sort orders
- The list of subscribed (news)groups / IMAP folders /  Gmail labels

(FAST) Information that changes quickly,  as messages are received and read and deleted

- which messages have been read or not in the various groups
- other metadata

Moreover, the (FAST) and  (SLOW) information is interleaved at fairly fine granularity within the  .newsrc.eld file.  multiple instances on the same very long line.  line oriented grep tools need not apply, but at least it's elisp so parsing  tools  should be available.

I most emphatically want to version control the  (SLOW) information --  the stuff that  I might've spent quite some time developing, which I would lose if the .newsrc* file(s)  were destroyed  or corrupted.

I do not need to version control the (FAST) information.  It changes too quickly,  behind the curtains. Sure, sometimes it's nice to  be able to recover it  after problems, but there's always the option of just  prefetching all messages in your subscribed groups in your existing topic hierarchy, and catching up.  Some lossage, but fast, certainly faster than rebuilding your subscriptions and topic hierarchy.

Similarly,  the list of subscribed (news)groups,  the topic hierarchy, and the sort ordering thereof, is reasonably portable between systems. Whereas the (FAST) information, e.g. which message numbers have been read or not, is  much less portable between systems. (E.g.  different NNTP servers accessing the same USENET newsgroups, and/or slightly inconsistent mirrors or archives of the same mailing lists.)

Of course,  one can simply `git checkin .newsrc.eld`  in much the same way one can version control binaries.  Note that this is more like version controlling a dynamic binary database;  version controlling a static set of binaries has reasonably good value, because you can tell when things were changed  infrequently,  even if it is hard to tell what the changes were.  Whereas version controlling the (FAST) information will always indicate changes.  It is just hard to tell if the changes matter or not because diffs  do not work very well.

I suppose  that in some ways what I'm really asking for is a good tool to diff  .newsrc ...  .newsrc.eld files,  where I can filter out the (FAST) changes  and only look at the (SLOW) changes that I care about. Which might be integrated with a version control tool like get to avoid doing you checkins if the (SLOW) information has not changed.

---

Summary:  what are the best ways to  manage files that have  mixtures of fast and slow information such as that in .newsrc.eld?    generic and/or emacs specific.

Comment: Perhaps pretty printing the.newsrc.eld. Elisp putting different data types/elements on different lines. ```Diff|grep -v message number ranges```, distinct from values I care about. I already transform XML in UTF 16 to UTF-8 to diff —- this goes just a step further to avoid checking in if the filtered stuff has not changed. // I wish I knew of a good tool to diff tree/nested data, that avoids miss leading deaths when an entire sub tree is moved. Many data formats need such.